# How to format decimal with leading zeros and without a separator?

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I have a requirement to format a decimal value into a 8 positions where the last 2 digits are reserved for decimal values.

The format should be: 00000000 (where the last 2 zeros are for decimal value).

Example:

Decimal Value: 193.45

> The result should be: 0000019345

Decimal Value: 245

> The result should be: 0000024500

I know that I can use `string.format("{format here}", value)` or `.ToString("format here")` but dont know what string format to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the MSDN documentation for [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx).

It would likely be possible to define a custom [NumberFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) to print strings in this format. However, a much easier way to accomplish this would be either of the following options:

```
(value * 100).ToString("00000000");

string.Format("{0:00000000}", value * 100);
```

Comment: I prefer this to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
decimalValue.ToString("00000000.00").Replace(".", "");
```

Comment: This works but there is no direct string format to do it? This is because Im going to store the format string in the DB, so I can change it anytime without altering my code.

Comment: @VAAA There is a [scaling specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx#SpecifierTh), but it divides, not multiplies, and by thousands, not hundreds.

Comment: This will break in some locales (eg. if `,` is used as decimal separator).

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just do `string` manipulation. I'm sure there *is* a format designator, but that seems easier.

```
string ret = (decimalValue * 100).ToString();

return ret.PadLeft(8, '0');
```

Comment: This will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, playing with the decimal type I found that by accessing its [binary representation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Decimal.ToByte);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) I was able to change the scale then format it to your requirements:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        decimal[] ds = { 193.45m, 245.00m };
        foreach (decimal d in ds)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Format8(d));
        }
    }

    static string Format8(decimal d)
    {
        int[] parts = decimal.GetBits(d);
        bool sign = (parts[3] & 0x80000000) != 0;

        byte scale = (byte)((parts[3] >> 16) & 0x7F);
        Debug.Assert(scale == 2);
        scale = 0; // alter scale to remove the point

        return new decimal(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], sign, scale)
            .ToString("00000000");
    }
}
```

One caveat is that if you have any data without two decimal points this approach would fail.